# Remove duplicated rows in dataframe in R

Tags: r, duplicates

I have a following problem:

My dataframe has a lot of columns. I would like to remove rows that have same values in column X, Y and Z.

See my dataframe:

```
A B C X Y Z
1 2 3 4 5 6
2 5 4 4 5 6
```

In the dataframe above I would like to delete the first row, because X, Y and Z are the same in both rows.

I tried this, but it returned me something different:

```
newtable <- df[!duplicated(df$X, df$Z, df$Z), ]
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: How about `df[!duplicated(df[-(1:3)]),]`?

Answer (score 1):

According to `?duplicated`, the usage is

> duplicated(x, incomparables = FALSE, ...)

where

> x- a vector or a data frame or an array or NULL.

i.e. it cannot take more than one argument for 'x'.  An option is to subset the dataset columns and apply as `x`

```
df[!duplicated(df[c("X", "Y", "Z")]), ]
```